# Vuetify How to change the padding of the dividers in a breadcrumb

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I need to change the padding of my dividers to 0, but can't access them even though they are list items

https://codepen.io/majesticpotatoe-the-bashful/pen/KKwXwBw

```
.v-breadcrumbs li {
  padding: 0px;
}
```

This CSS above didn't do the trick

Answer (score 1):

This CSS works:

```css
.v-breadcrumbs__divider {
  padding: 0 !important;
}
```

[updated codepen](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/ZELpoXw)